# Subtracting date in php

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to make a program that subtracts the user's inputted birthdate and the date today.

Here is my code:

```
$bday = $_POST['bday']; //user input 

$today=date("Y-m-d");
$myage= $today - $bday; //i got a warning message here saying "A non-numeric value encountered"
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `date()` returns a string, `$_POST['bday']` likely is a string as well, so neither can be subtracted

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet, Assuming you are requiring days and/or years as a result. I used the `date_diff` function for this code. Converting the user input into date/time( has the Y-m-d format) also I hard coded the user input for easier visualisation.

**Working Snippet:**

```
$input="2013-12-12"; #User input
$date = strtotime($input); #Convert user input to date time
$date1=date_create(date("Y-m-d")); #date today
$date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d', $date)); #inputted date
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); #date_diff function 


echo $diff->format("%Y years or %a days");
```

**Output:**

```
8 years or 3123 days
```

There is possibly a cleaner version of this. But I believe this is the right flow for your requirements.